# How to fix non accessible method

Tags: javascript, java, methods, bluej

When I create an object of the class `Championship`, it shows there are no accessible methods.

```
public class Championship 
            {
                private ListOfDrivers driversList;
                private ListOfVenues venuesList;
                private RNG rand;

                public static void main(String[] args) {
                    Championship sim = new Championship();
                    sim.startgame();
                }


                private void startgame() 
                {
                    this.driversList = new ListOfDrivers();
                    this.venuesList = new ListOfVenues();
                    this.rand = new RNG();
                    System.out.println("List of venues:");
                    venuesList.printVenues();

                    System.out.println("And  starts....");
                    for(Venue venue : venuesList.getVenues()) {
                        System.out.println("------------------------------------------------------------");
                        System.out.println("Welcome one and all to " + venue.getVenueName() + "!");

                        // Give race penalties at the start of the race
                        for(Driver driver: driversList.getDrivers()) {
                            switch(driver.getRanking()) {
                                case 1: driver.setTime(0); break;
                                case 2: driver.setTime(3); break;
                                case 3: driver.setTime(5); break;
                                case 4: driver.setTime(7); break;
                                default: driver.setTime(10);
                            }
                        }
                        System.out.println("Drivers list!");
                        driversList.printDrivers();

                        System.out.println("Race starts!!");
                        for(int lap = 1; lap<=venue.getNoOfLaps(); lap++) {
                            System.out.println("In Lap " + lap + " now..");
                            for(Driver driver: driversList.getDrivers()) {
                                if(driver.getEligibleToRace())
                                {
                                    int faultRand = rand.faultRNG();
                                    if(faultRand == 1) 
                                    {
                                        System.out.println(driver.getName() + " just had an unrecoverable mechanical fault!!");
                                        System.out.println(driver.getName() + " is out of the race..");
                                        driver.setEligibleToRace(false);
                                        driver.setTime(99999);
                                        continue;
                                    } 
                                    else if(faultRand <=3) 
                                    {
                                        System.out.println(driver.getName() + " just had a major mechanical fault!!");
                                        driver.increaseTime(120);
                                    }
                                    else if(faultRand <=5)
                                    {
                                        System.out.println(driver.getName() + " just had a minor mechanical fault!!");
                                        driver.increaseTime(20);
                                    }

                                    driver.increaseTime(venue.getAverageLapTime());

                                    if(driver.getSkill().equals("Overtaking")) 
                                    {
                                        if(lap%3 == 1) {
                                            int reduc = rand.timeReductionRNG(10, 20);
                                            driver.decreaseTime(reduc);
                                            System.out.println(driver.getName() + " reduced time of " + reduc + " seconds");
                                        }
                                    } else
                                    {
                                        int reduc = rand.timeReductionRNG(1, 8);
                                        driver.decreaseTime(reduc);
                                        System.out.println(driver.getName() + " reduced time of " + reduc + " seconds");
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            Driver currentRaceLeader = driversList.lowestTime();
                            System.out.println("Lap " + lap + " statistics:");
                            System.out.println("Leader: " + currentRaceLeader.getName() + "\tTotal Time: " + 
                                currentRaceLeader.getTime() + " seconds");
                        }

                        System.out.println("The championship race at " + venue.getVenueName() + " has concluded!");
                        driversList.allocateScores();
                        System.out.println("Results are: ");
                        String format = "%20s | %8s | %10s | %8s ";
                        System.out.println(String.format(format, "Name", "Ranking", "Race Time", "Score"));
                        for(Driver driver : driversList.getDrivers()) {
                            if(driversList.getDrivers().get(4) == driver) 
                                break;
                            System.out.println(String.format(format, driver.getName(), driver.getRanking(),
                                    driver.getTime(), driver.getScore()));
                        }
                    }
                    System.out.println("------------------------------");
                    System.out.println("Championship has concluded and the champion is:");
                    Driver winner = driversList.highestScore();
                    System.out.println(winner.getName() + " with a total of " + winner.getScore() + " points!!");
                    System.out.println("------------------------------");
                }
            }
```

When I click on the object, it shows that there are no accessible methods and hence I​ cannot start the simulation. Is there something that i'm missing? The code compiles just fine and there is no error message whatsover. Still it doesn't let me simulate when i create a new object of the class championship.

Comment: What do you mean "no accessible methods"?  You are calling `sim.startgame()` in your constructor, and you say that it compiles just fine.

Comment: I am confused as well, where does this error message appear and what exactly is it?

Comment: "javascript"???

Comment: This is not javascript, it's java.

Comment: I mean when I create an object of the class championship and then try to access any method by right-clicking on the object, it shows that there are no accessible methods present.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, all of the methods except for the default constructor for `Championship` objects are marked as private and therefore only accessible internally to the class implementation itself.

As soon as you instantiate an instance of `Championship` object the `startgame()` method is automatically called.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  Championship sim = new Championship();
  sim.startgame();
}
```

If you want to be able to create instances of `Championship` without immediately invoking the `startgame()` method, or call the `startgame()` method outside instantiation - mark `startgame()` `public` and/or remove `sim.startgame()` from the constructor.

Method prototype should match

```
public void startgame() {
  ...
}
```